# is AntiXss 4.2 safe to use instead of AntiXss 3

Tags: asp.net, antixsslibrary

I wanted to use new AntiXSS 4.2 in my new project , but there were [discussions](http://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/80289) about its bugs and aggressive behavior in encoding and removing html elements . so I don't know what to do ?

still use version 3.0 or upgrade to 4.2.1 ?

one thing I noticed myself is that in previous version when I bind an encoded text to a textbox ,it shows text normally but in this new version shows the text in codes . and I have to decode before binding to textbox

any idea or suggestion is appreciated .